# Prepositions before infinitives? ... "to come back from injury"

Tags: verbes, ordre-des-mots

> To come back from injury to run a marathon, and to run a personal best to boot - it's just incredible!

I'm just wondering how to structure this in French - I imagine you would also use the infinitive, but don't know if I need some sort of preposition to get the exact meaning across. My instinct was to use "pour revenir" but feel like that would translate more to "in order to come back". Perhaps in French it just wouldn't be phrased this way and I'm overcomplicating things!

Any help would be appreciated!
Merci :)

Answer (score 5):

It's fine to use **only the infinitive** in this context:

> Revenir de blessure et courir un marathon, et en plus battre son record personnel, c'est juste incroyable !

This is an example of infinitive [used as a noun](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4217).

Comment: +1 for this answer and jiliagre's : a plain infinitive is indicated in this case, and I can't think of any alternative way. However, if I may offer a frenchier translation : "Récupérer d'une blessure et courir un marathon, et battre son record personnel par-dessus le marché, c'est tout simplement incroyable !"

Comment: Thanks for your take at this translation! I think your proposal is more rigorous than mine, which sounds a bit more like spoken French. I must say that I always heard "revenir de blessure" in the sports context personally.

Comment: @jwav "To come back from injury" (*revenir*) is not the same than "to recover from injury" (*récupérer*). To come back is happening at a point in time while to recover is something gradual.

Comment: @jiliagre I might be wrong, then. It's true that "récupérer d'une blessure" would translate as "recover from an injury" rather than "come back from an injury". It's just that I've never heard or read "revenir de blessure" or "revenir d'une blessure" so I assumed it was an English calque. After checking, it seems that it is indeed used in sports. Thanks for letting me learn something :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a preposition:

> Revenir de blessure pour directement courir un marathon, et battre son record personnel par dessus le marché, c'est tout simplement incroyable !